# How to get IOGEAR GBU521 bluetooth dongle to work?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

How do I get it to work? Dongle is plugged into usb port. Headphones in search mode. Bluetooth manager not detecting anything. IOGEAR website only shows drivers for Windows. Running Lubuntu 16.10 on a Dell Inspiron E1505. I'm a newbie to Linux.

Here's lsusb -v partial output. The full output is quite lengthy. Can post if needed.

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:

```
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         1
  bDeviceProtocol         1 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0a5c Broadcom Corp.
  idProduct          0x21e8 BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
  bcdDevice            1.12
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1�
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lsusb`